# application.properties in a project hierarchy

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot has a config file named "application.properties" or "application.yml". My Spring Boot application is called "**A**".
My problem is that with these properties files  when other applications depend on application **A**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.baharan</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-releases</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I have applications **A**, **B** and **C**.
**B** and **C** depend on **A**, so I had to move "application.properties" of **A** to **B** and **C** then **B** and **C** started successfully.
**B** and **C** share some property values, so I'd like to put 
these common values into application.properties of **A** and only put project-specific values into **B**'s and **C**'s configuration.

Comment: try to look at spring profiles. You can probably rename application.properties by application-<name>.properties (<name> could be A, B or C). And then when starting the applications use those profiles. For example when you will start application B you can run it with property spring.profiles.active=A,B

Comment: The real source of your problems is that "A" is a Spring Boot application. Spring Boot (or Spring Framework, for that matter) is not a library framework, it should only be used for top-level applications.